# How can I access this asp.net Panel control in a user control and make it visible?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET Web Forms developer and I am struggling right now with hiding a part of the user control in some of the pages which have it based on certain factors.

ASP.NET code of the user control:

```
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlView" runat="server" CssClass="panel">
                <span class="lead text-info">This is a simple test user control</span>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlActions" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" Text="Confirm" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                    OnClick="btnConfirm_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnReject" runat="server" Text="Reject" CssClass="btn btn-danger"
                    OnClick="btnReject_Click" />
                <asp:Label ID="lblInfo" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="label label-info"></asp:Label>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Code-Behind of the user control:

```
protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblInfo.Text = "Confirmed";
    }


    protected void btnReject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblInfo.Text = "Rejected";
    }
```

The asp.net panel with id "pnlActions" should be displayed based on the username of the user who is going to access the .aspx page that has this user control. **So how can I do that?**

Here's the ASP.NET code of the .aspx page:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <span class="lead">This is the user control</span>
        <uc:TestUserControl ID="TestUserControl1" runat="server"></uc:TestUserControl>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="well">
            The user control on the left side has an asp.net panel control which
        has two buttons. These two buttons should be shown if the user 
        is an administrator, and they should be hidden for the rest of users.
        This user control will be used on four pages across this test application.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code-behind of the .aspx page:

```
 string username = "JohnA";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (username == "JohnA")
    {
        //pnlActions control in the user control should be displayed
    }
    else
    { 
        //pnlActions control should be hidden
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make a `bool` property in `TestUserControl` and that property will manage `pnlActions` control visibility. And then you should be able to set it from `Page_Load`

Comment: Dear @SergeyLitvinov, thank you for your help. However, could you please provide me with a simple code snippet that is applicable to my code?

Comment: Thanks @SergeyLitvinov, I could be able to solve it now.

Answer (score 0):

These control specific actions should be placed in your user controls code behind, rather than in your pages layout, to provide more modularity.

Later the goal is to put all of these custom components in different variations on the page, thats the point of custom user controls.

You can´t accomplish that by putting business logic of your individual components in the layout.

If you really want to do that you can do it by exposing your panels by public properties in your controls code behind or modifing the designer code(not always a good idea...).

You could read into this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28783/Your-First-ASP-NET-Custom-Control

Answer (score 0):

try to find control by id in user control code .

or there is a step to get the page control first who hosts the user control and then find the control by id  from that page . once u have reference to your control you can definitely do all operations.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following line in the user control.

this.Master.FindControl("pnlView").Visible = true;